# Mandrill webhook authentication-signature not matched

Tags: node.js, authentication, mailchimp, signature, mandrill

Mandrill webhook authentication-verify signature

For node js

example verify signature

please check the code below

But its working only for event types like send, reject. Not working for event types like open, click & others

```
function generateSignature(webhook_key, url, params) {
  var signed_data = url;
  const param_keys = Object.keys(params);
  param_keys.sort();
  param_keys.forEach(function (key) {
      signed_data += key + params[key];
  }); 

  hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', webhook_key);
  hmac.update(signed_data);

  return hmac.digest('base64');
}

let url = "https://your-app-domain.com/default/MandrillXP-new";
let key = "abcd1234"; //your mandrill webhook api key

let bodyPayload;
if(event.isBase64Encoded){
  bodyPayload = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64').toString()
}else{
  bodyPayload = event.body
} 
  let splitData = req.body.split("=")
  let decodeData = decodeURIComponent(splitData[1]);    

var generatedSignature = generateSignature(key, url, { "mandrill_events": decodeData })

if (req.headers["x-mandrill-signature"]!== generatedSignature) {
  console.log("signature mismatch")
}else{
  console.log("signature  matched")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace '+' with ' '(space) in string before encode

var decodeData = decodeData .replace(/[+]/g, ' ');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).